# Django query that requires grouping and aggregating

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to do this query in django and I'm not sure what the best way to do it is. I neeed to group and then count and order by that count...

I have a through model like:

```
ProjectView(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
  datetime_created = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to get a list of projects ordered by most views since yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (not tested):

```
projects = Project.objects \
                  .annotate(total_views=Count('projectview__project'))
                  .order_by('-total_views')
```

Where `Project` is the model name and `projectview` is the `through` table.

Comment: This only returns a list of project ids....i need all the project model data (title, owner, thumbnail etc)